# this.state.post.map is not a function

Tags: json, reactjs

I am receiving json data from server and i am trying to access it individually using map function in front end  but i am receiving an error as this.state.post.map is not a function. below is the code how do i overcome this.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
//require('./style.scss');

class Premontessori extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      post:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let self = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        self.setState({post:data});
      });
   }

   render(){
     return (
       <div>
         <table>
            <tbody>
               {
                 this.state.post.map(function(item, index){
                    return (
                       <tr>
                         <td>{item.Id}</td>
                         <td>{item.Name}</td>
                         <td>{item.Age}</td>
                       </tr>
                    )
                  })
                }
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
      );
   }
}
export default Premontessori;
```

Comment: try console.log(this.state.post) int the render function and see if you get an array because you can map over an array

Comment: i am receiving object as Object {data: Array[2], status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment,
'since `this.state.post` is not an array hence you get an error that map is not a function.

You need to map over the data in the post object like

```
 <tbody>
       {this.state.post.data.map(function(item, index) {
             return (
                <tr key={index}>

                  <td>{item.Id}</td>
                  <td>{item.Name}</td>
                  <td>{item.Age}</td>
                </tr>
            )
         })
       }
       </tbody>
```

Comment: console.log(this.state.post.data)  in render function and see if you get an array

Comment: it does not display anything. can i use map and key value to display it

Comment: Try and setState in componentDidMount axios call as `self.setState({post: data.data})` and then access it like console.log(this.state.post) and see if your get the array

Comment: ya now i am getting. but what does  "data.data"  do and i am getting an warning as   Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: simple enough, data is something that you get as response and data.data will give your the object data from the response. The unique key problem is easy to solve. check the updated answer. add `key={index}` to the table row

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make an adjustment in the code in the `componentDidMount` life-cycle method as shown below. This is because the response from the axios call is wrapping the array data, so you have to fetch that array and update your state if the status code is 200.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
//require('./style.scss');

class Premontessori extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      post:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let self = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(res.status === 200){
          self.setState({post:res.data});
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
       });
    }

    render(){
      return (
       <div>
         <table>
           <tbody>
           {
             this.state.post.map(function(item, index){
                return (
                   <tr>
                     <td>{item.Id}</td>
                     <td>{item.Name}</td>
                     <td>{item.Age}</td>
                   </tr>
                  )
                })
              }
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   );
 }
}
export default Premontessori;
```